# How do I access the Lubuntu menu in Openbox?

Tags: openbox, lubuntu

Is there a way to include the Lubuntu applications menu in an Openbox menu (`~/.config/openbox/menu.xml`) so I can use it within a pure Openbox session?

Comment: Does [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/196614/273670) from AskUbuntu help?

Answer (score 0):

lxpanel use .desktop files for menu and openbox use xml(menu.xml)
so you need a converter, for example:
http://obmenugen.sourceforge.net/

> Generates a full menu for openbox using the information present in *.desktop files (with static content or dinamically generated).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [Pipe menu](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aMenus#Pipe_menus).

A pipe menu is a dynamic menu item that is created by a program every time the menu is opened.

There are multiple programs that can create a pipe menu of the installed applications. Here is a list of [featured pipe menus](http://openbox.org/wiki/Openbox%3aPipemenus#XDG_Application_Menus) from Openbox.org.

Since you use Lubuntu you would most likely be interested in [openbox-menu](http://fabrice.thiroux.free.fr/openbox-menu_en.html). It uses the menu cache of LXDE to create the application menu. There is a Ubuntu package [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openbox-menu). I don't know if it is in the official repository, you should check that.

To use a pipe menu you need to edit your Openbox menu file at `~/.config/openbox/menu.xml`.

In your menu file you need to add a new menu item under your `root-menu` that looks like this

```
<menu id="desktop-app-menu"
      label="Applications"
      execute="<path-to-exec>/openbox-menu" />
```

You will need to replace `<path-to-exec>` which the path to `openbox-menu`.
You can get the path with

```
type openbox-menu
```

Then you will have a new menu item labeled Applications in your Openbox menu.

It you never edited your `menu.xml` take a look at the [menu documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aMenus) from Openbox.